# Sum based on range in separate columns

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

I want to calculate the sum of y along the x-axis. The range for summation is contained in the separate columns xmin and xmax.

```
df <- data.frame (group = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B" ),
              x = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
              y= c(1,2,3,2,1,4,5,6,5,4),
              xmin=c(2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1),
              xmax=c(4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5))
```

For group A that is a range x from 2 to 4, sum{2+3+2}=7
For group B, range x from 1 to 5 sum{4+5+6+5+4}=24

Is there a way to do it?

I have tried around a bit but I'm not sure if the following goes in the right direction

```
 df  %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(sumX=sum(df$y[df$x>=df$min & df$x<=df$max]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `between` to `subset`, then just `sum` in `tapply`.

```
subset(df, do.call(data.table::between, c(list(x), list(xmin, xmax)))) |>
  with(tapply(y, group, sum))
# A  B 
# 7 24
```

*Note:* R >= 4.1 used.

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B"), x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), y = c(1, 2, 3, 
2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4), xmin = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    xmax = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Thank you, your code works well!  However since I am only familiar with some basics of R, I can't figure out how to implement your code. This was only a minimalistic example, I have several group columns in my data frame. Is it possible to calculate these values based on several groups and append them to the existing data frame with mutate or something similar?   So for group A, there are several xmin-xmax ranges.

Comment: @Envoy1 The answer uses only four commands, you easily may look up in the respective help pages if they are new to you. Expand your knowledge, try harder! If the minimal example you provide doesn't fit your problem you may want to improve it. It's also wise to define an expected output.